# Trying to make a script to search a directory for folders containing files of a certain extension then move it, directory hierarchy intact

Tags: windows, powershell

I'd like to write a script to search a directory, let's say `C:\books`, and search subdirectories for files of a specific extension, let's say `.mp3` for example.

Then if the folder contains such files, I want to move it with the folder hierarchy intact to a new directory. So let's say `C:\books\harry_potter\goblet` contains an `.mp3` file, it would move to `C:\audiobooks\harry_potter\goblet`, after asking for confirmation.

I am thinking PowerShell cmdlet `Get-ChildItem` is my best bet piped into a `Move-Item`, but I am a complete noob with PowerShell scripting. I'd really appreciate any advice.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` and `Move-Item` are definitely good bets :) What have you tried so far?

Comment: You've got two separate tasks to accomplish: 1) finding the files, and 2) moving the folders and files. So start by searching here for `powershell search folders for files` and work on that part. Then search here for the other part, and get that working. Then put them together. If you get stuck on the way, you can post the code you've written, explain the problem, and ask a specific question we can try to answer. We're not a code writing service, though; we do expect you to put some effort into solving the problem yourself first.

Comment: I've gotten as far as:

Comment: `$OrgPath = Read-host "Enter File Path"
$NewPath = Read-host "Enter Destination Folder"
$Ext = Read-host "Enter file extension"
$files = get-childitem -recurse -file | where {$_.extension -match "$Ext"}

Foreach($file In $files)
{
    $Directory = ($file.fullname.split("\")[0..($file.fullname.split("\").count -2)] -join "\").replace("$OrgPath","$NewPath")
    if((Test-path -path $Directory) -eq $False)
    {
         new-item $Directory -type directory
    }
    Move-Item -path $File.fullname -destination $directory -WhatIf
}
`

Comment: I think there's something going wrong at the .replace() point of the script, as I am definitely not getting the files to move to the new folder and some of the directories are triggering an error at the new-item saying the directory already exists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do in the root of the collection:

```
(ls *.mp3 -recurse) | % { split-path $_ } | sort -u | % { cp $_ $_.Replace('c:\books', 'c:\audiobooks') }
```

I used `cp` instead of `mv` for you to test it without moving files around. Explanation: the `ls` returns all files, `%` then gets their parent, `sort -u` removes duplicates among parents, and the last command moves each parent to new location.

Comment: Thanks for such a concise and elegant solution, but I seem to still have a problem.  I am getting the following error: `The regular expression pattern I:\Ebooks and PDFs is not valid.
At line:1 char:65
+ ... t -u | % { cp $_ $($_ -replace 'I:\Ebooks and PDFs','I:\Audiobooks')}
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (I:\Ebooks and PDFs:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression`.  Do any idea what is triggering the exception?

Comment: instead of `$($_ -replace ... )` use `$_.Replace( a, b)`. See edited answer.

Comment: This worked great to copy, but when I replaced cp with mv (I added -force since the directories are now already populated) I was given a cannot move item because the original directory is in use exception.  I closed every possible program I had running that might be using the directory, and still receive the exception.  Is there a possible syntax problem or can you see a reason for this?

Comment: Apparently it moved the files and then gave the exception which is a win in my book.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark the answer as solution.

Comment: The directory used exception is probably due to the way `ls` is used. If you put it in the parenthesis it should solve that. See edited answer.